# What is the meaning of か in といったところか

Tags: particle-か

I have two examples:

> 噂に違{たが}わぬと言ったところか. -- Then, he really lives up to the rumor!
>   この建物の建設にかかる費用はおおよそ100億円といったところか -- That would mean that we need 10 million to build this building!

I would bet that か here is used in the following sense 驚きや感動の気持ちを表す。(that is how I translated it above). Is it really so?

Related question: Ending a sentence like that may seem blunt. How it is possible to keep the tone of surprise (as long as I have guessed right) but with a softer ending?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I would bet that か here is used in the following sense 驚きや感動の気持ちを表す。(that is how I translated it above). Is it really so?

I am afraid that is not the case.

「～～といったところか」 simply means "***I would say ~~~***".  It implies that the statement would at least be fairly accurate if not 100% accurate.

This is a way of talking as much to yourself as to your listeners/readers.  It is a way of avoiding clear declaration as well.  It softens the tone of the statement compared to sentence endings such as 「～～である」、「～～だ」, etc.

It seems that you were thinking of the 「か」 used　 as in:

「このメロンは二万円{にまんえん}もするの**か**！」 = "What?  This melon costs 20,000 yen?!"

That 「か」 would certainly express 驚{おどろ}きや感動{かんどう}の気持{きも}ち.

Comment: "I am afraid that is not the case." >> I am glad I asked them. Thank you very much.