Meaning of 腐っても女神ってところか
In Konosuba chapter 3, they were talking about capabilities of a powerful monster リッチー. Kazuma thought

神に敵対する大物アンテッドだからアクアが反応したんだな
腐っても女神ってところか

I think he is saying that "even if she is useless (?), she is still a goddess." I wonder what nuance does ってところか add here. How it is different from ってことか?


You didn't mention it, so I figured I'd just check, but are you familiar with the expression 腐っても鯛?

@Leebo Nah, I've never learned it. So it's a wordplay?

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46513/5010
